# TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler not found in latest spring-security-oauth2-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

```
<bean id="userApprovalHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
  <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
</bean>
```

The following code in my spring-security.xml was working with spring-security-oauth2-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar but when I upgraded it to spring-security-oauth2-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar the above file ie, "org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler" was not found.

I was doing this because with previous jar there was some conflict regarding jackson due to Spring 4.1.X

```
17:14:53,679 WARN [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices
com.aricent.ans.controller.um.UserController.tokenServices; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tokenServices' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]: Cannot
resolve reference to bean 'clientDetails' while setting bean property 'clientDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientDetails' defined in ServletContext resource
[/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.JdbcClientDetailsService]: Constructor
threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper
```

Comment: did you find solution? even I am stuck with the same error.

Comment: No I didn't find the solution as you can see already on this post. As a workaround I commented the parts in xml requiring "userApprovalHandler". I think this part is already handled in jar somehow and we do not need to handle it explicitly. Comment it out until you get an answer to get your code running. If you find an answer, please enlighten me too. Hope it help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was a change with the version of Spring OAuth2 you're using. Try this:

```
<bean id="userApprovalHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
</bean>
```